# Loop through a query result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where users can input/enter up to 5 interests. Now, I want to display the user's interests to the user in form fields. This gives them the ability to directly edit them.

First what I do is query the rows of data relating to the user, in my interests table. Then, I use mysqli_num_rows to determine the variables I have to make. Then, I manually loop through the array to create each variable.

But there is a problem, it doesn't cycle to the next row of data. So for instance `$interest1` will equal `$interest2`, and `$interest3` will do the same. And so on and so forth. This is not what I want to happen. `$interest2, 3, 4, and 5` should all equal the next row of data. What am I possibly doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$result2= mysqli_query($connect, $query2);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) != 0) {

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) == 1) {
        $row2= mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
        $interest1= $row2['interest'];
        }
        else if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) == 2) {
        $row2= mysqli_fetch_array($result2);            
        $interest1= $row2['interest'];
        $interest2= $row2['interest'];          
        }
        else if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) == 3) {
        $row2= mysqli_fetch_array($result2);            
        $interest1= $row2['interest'];
        $interest2= $row2['interest'];
        $interest3= $row2['interest'];
        }
        else if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) == 4) {
        $row2= mysqli_fetch_array($result2);            
        $interest1= $row2['interest'];
        $interest2= $row2['interest'];
        $interest3= $row2['interest'];
        $interest4= $row2['interest'];      
        }
        else if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) == 5) {
        $row2= mysqli_fetch_array($result2);            
        $interest1= $row2['interest'];
        $interest2= $row2['interest'];
        $interest3= $row2['interest'];
        $interest4= $row2['interest'];
        $interest5= $row2['interest'];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to loop through this (as you said), but also, to store your results in an array, as you're already (basically) using array format to store it in separate variables:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $query2);
$interests = array();
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $interests[] = $result['interest'];
}
print_r($interests);
```

As per your issue with the values not being set, it's because you're not looping through the rows, rather you're accessing a single array each time and setting it to different variables.

Comment: @user1592953, Manually loop? PHP retains the GOTO syntax, but it's not very usable and is completely outdated, why do you need to manually loop, and what does that exactly mean to you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   $result2= mysqli_query($connect, $query2);
       while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
      {
        $interest[]= $row['interest'];

      }

print_r($interest)//Array of itnerest
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you're trying to do.
But your code within each IF case is repeatedly getting the same value from `mysqli_num_rows($result2)`, just a different number of times for each case.